# Avoid duplicate entries in known_hosts file when using sftp application

Tags: sftp, duplicates

I have written a java sftp application based on Jcraft.jsch running on solaris. Each time the application connects to remote host a duplicate entry is done in known_hosts file. Any help on how to stop this. The connection code is as below:

public boolean connect(Properties props) throws JSchException {

```
 FileSystemOptions fso = new FileSystemOptions();  
 try {  
       SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setStrictHostKeyChecking(fso, "no");  
       session = SftpClientFactory.createConnection(host, port, login.toCharArray(), password.toCharArray(), fso);  
        Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");  
        channel.connect();  
        command = (ChannelSftp) channel;  

    } catch (FileSystemException e) {    ...
```

Thanks